# kafka send messages to all consumers that have the same group.id

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

By default Kafka is sending the messages from a topic to all consumer groups.

In my case I have a few microservices that need to rescale. Let's say we have three instances of each one.

I have a service that provides data necessary for each of the microservices. This service is publishing the needed data but the problem is that only one instance of each micro app will be initialized when a message is published.

I need to find a way to send the data to all the instances of each microservice. This is mandatory metadata.

I do not know how to obtain this behavior and I cannot change the `group.id`s because then the services will consume the same messages twice.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I found the answer.

I can obtain this be defining multiple listeners in the application. Each listeners will subscribe to it's topic and each listener will be part of a different `group.id`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#_annotation_properties

From the spring kafka docs we can see that the kafka listener annotation accepts as params the topics and the group ID.

In this way I can have three instances of the app I1, I2, I3 with the following config:

```
T1:
 @KafkaListener(topics = "ORDER_TOPIC", groupId = "order_consumer_group")
 @KafkaListener(topics = "METADATA_TOPIC", groupId = "metadata_topic_uuid1")
T2:
 @KafkaListener(topics = "ORDER_TOPIC", groupId = "order_consumer_group")
 @KafkaListener(topics = "METADATA_TOPIC", groupId = "metadata_topic_uuid2")
T3:
 @KafkaListener(topics = "ORDER_TOPIC", groupId = "order_consumer_group")
 @KafkaListener(topics = "METADATA_TOPIC", groupId = "metadata_topic_uuid3")
```

Comment: Please provide more details as the solution posted by you seems incomplete. Complete , logical & understandable solution might help others too!!